# Integration of Rails and Django app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django

What would the sensible way to integrate multiple web applications. At this point I think they will all be on Rails. Is Rails engines the way to go or can it be hacked via the view / html?

What if two were Rails and one was Django?

I'd like the apps to be able to share data, and display portions of views from one app inside another view on the master Rails app.

Comment: They are completely different frameworks so they won't be able to integrate cleanly. You can (try) share data from the DB but you won't be able to display one view in the other - it doesn't make sense. You would be best doing everything in a single framework

Comment: Hey thanks Timmy. I used to work with Oracle enterprise products, and they manage to weave together pieces from different apps via their portal products. Anything similar in the open source world?

Comment: Hi Timmy - can you put your response as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are completely different frameworks so they won't be able to integrate cleanly. You can (try) share data from the DB but you won't be able to display one view in the other - it doesn't make sense. You would be best doing everything in a single framework